Strict stubbing argument mismatch - MongoDB, Spring Boot 3> JUnit testing
I have to create JUnit tests for Spring Boot 3.3.3 application, using MongoDB.
This is my model class and then, example of code i put in every testing class - for controller, service and repository, I need to do this:
@Document(collection = "Notes")
public class Note {

    @Id
    private String id; //(auto-generated UUID or MongoDB ObjectId)
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
...}

TestNoteService class:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class TestNoteService {

    @Mock
    private NotesRepository notesRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private NoteService noteService;


    private Note note;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        note = Note.builder()
                .id("sghgak17")
                .title("Title")
                .content("Testing Content.")
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .updatedAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void createNoteTest() {
        // precondition
        given(notesRepository.save(note)).willReturn(note);
        //action
        Note savedNote = noteService.createNote(note); 
        // verify the output
        System.out.println(savedNote);
        //assertThat(savedNote).isNotNull();
    }
    }

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem:  Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:

this invocation of 'save' method: notesRepository.save( Note(id=5f3623af, title=Title, content=Testing Content., createdAt=2024-12-20T19:15:31.742424500, updatedAt=2024-12-20T19:15:31.742424500) );
-> at com.beetexting.service.NoteService.createNote(NoteService.java:27)

has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:

notesRepository.save(    Note(id=sghgak17, title=Title, content=Testing Content., createdAt=2024-12-20T19:15:31.706903600, updatedAt=2024-12-20T19:15:31.707903400) );
-> at com.beetexting.service.TestNoteService.createNoteTest(TestNoteService.java:54) Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests. Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily. However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:


stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API   Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.

stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test     Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT). For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.
    at com.beetexting.service.NoteService.createNote(NoteService.java:27)           at com.beetexting.service.TestNoteService.createNoteTest(TestNoteService.java:58)           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)           at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)           at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)



Obviously, the note and savedNote are not the same - the ids (unique Primary Keys) are different.
How to solve this?
Thanks.

missing code????

I had a problem to post the code!?  So, I split  the post in couple of editing circles.

I tried this:
given(notesRepository.save(any())).willReturn(note);
and it seems to work.
